# Allow user to enter Alt code into a TMemo?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

TMemo in FMX supports the display of Alt codes, but the only way I can add them is by copying them from elsewhere and pasting them into the TMemo. I'd like to allow users to enter Alt codes using the Alt key and number pad in the same way that most text editors allow. Currently when I try this it does nothing. The number pad works but not when Shift, Ctrl or Alt are pressed.

Alt codes can be entered in VCL applications. I'd just like to be able to do the same in FMX.

I'm using Delphi 10.4

Comment: If you set `ControlType` to `Platform` and run the application on Microsoft Windows, you will get a true Win32 edit control, which supports this.

Comment: Thanks. That works. However, I need this to work on Mac as well. Would it work there too (I'm not able to test currently)? Also, I now have greyed out scroll bars on the right and bottom of the TMemo even with no text. They're not shown in VCL. Is there any way to get rid of them until they're needed?

Comment: No idea! I have never used a Mac all my life! Unfortunately, the native Win32 edit control doesn't support showing/hiding scroll bars dynamically depending on its content. (However, the Win32 Rich Edit control does support that.)

Comment: Are ALT codes even a thing on the Mac?

Comment: OK, thanks. I may just turn off scoll bars completely then or use the rich edit.

Comment: I assumed they were David but I've never used a Mac either. Apparently they work using the option key but not in the same way as on Windows (no number pad for a start).

Comment: You probably have to enter them with an externally attached device that costs £1,800 and is made from brushed aluminium.